# Collate several xdebug coverage results into one report?

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using the [php-code-coverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage) to collect coverage information from one HTTP request (thru apache). I'd like to store the coverage data from several requests, and then collate the results into one comprehensive report.

Is this easy to do? I was hoping for something along the lines of:

```
<?php
require 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Autoload.php';

$coverage = new PHP_CodeCoverage;
$coverage->start('<some request>');

// ...

$coverage->stop();

$writer = new PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XXX;
$writer->process($coverage, '/tmp/reportYYY.xml');


// at some later date, collate all the results.
$writer = new PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML;
$writer->process('/tmp/reportX.xml');
// ...
$writer->process('/tmp/reportZ.xml');
```

Comment: See https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/198

Comment: Ha, thanks - I opened that ticket! I haven't tried the method outlined in the response; but it does sound like using https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcov work, with some fiddling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get this running using [phpcov](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpcov) (installed via composer) as mentioned:

Using Apache .htaccess to prepend/append php scripts that serialize PHP_CodeCoverage object to file, you'll need to adjust paths appropriately:

.htaccess:

```
# Prepend the file
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php" 

# Append file to bottom of page
php_value auto_append_file "append.php"
```

prepend.php:

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
$coverage = new PHP_CodeCoverage;
$coverage->start('Site coverage');
```

append.php:

```
<?php

$coverage->stop();
$cov = serialize($coverage); //serialize object to disk
file_put_contents('../cov/site.' . date('U') . '.cov', $cov);
```

Because I'm serializing the object I had to edit /vendor/phpunit/phpcov/src/MergeCommand.php:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $mergedCoverage = new PHP_CodeCoverage;

    $finder = new FinderFacade(
        array($input->getArgument('directory')),
        array(),
        array('*.cov')
    );

    foreach ($finder->findFiles() as $file) {
        print "Merging $file" . PHP_EOL;
        //$_coverage = include($file);
        $_coverage = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
        $mergedCoverage->merge($_coverage);
        unset($_coverage);
    }

    $this->handleReports($mergedCoverage, $input, $output);
}
```

Then using phpcov, create the report:

```
./vendor/bin/phpcov merge --html="./cov/report/" ./cov -vvv
```

Comment: If someone can edit to use include instead (and not require editing the vendor package) that would be better.

Comment: great trick with .htaccess! I'll just add that it's best to use "register_shutdown_function" rather than using append.php. Otherwise, exit() traces will not be saved.

Comment: I used `$cov = '<?php return unserialize(' . var_export(serialize($coverage), true) . ');';` instead of `$cov = serialize($coverage);` to remove the requirement to edit `MergeCommand.php`.

Comment: **Note:** If the script is terminated with *exit()*, *auto-append* will **not occur**.

Use *register_shutdown_function()* function in your *prepend* file instead of *auto_append_file* value.

Comment: PHPCoverage has a built-in function to get the proper output without serializing: `$cov = (new PHP)->process($coverage);`