# Slim framework and code coverage

Tags: php, xdebug

I am trying to use xdebug to compute code coverage of a slim application. The results seems erroneous, as it tells me that all code within routes handlers is not executed (and i did some requests...)

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
xdebug_start_code_coverage(XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED | XDEBUG_CC_DEAD_CODE);
$app->get('/data', function () use ($app) {
  echo "data";
});
$app->get('/STOP', function () use ($app) {
  $data = xdebug_get_code_coverage();
  var_dump($data);
});
$app->run();
```

I run the server using:

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t . test.php
```

And then perform two requests:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/server.php/data
curl http://localhost:8080/server.php/STOP > result.html
```

The coverage output in `result.html` tells me:

```
'.../test.php' => 
array (size=11)
  0 => int 1
  5 => int 1
  6 => int -1
  7 => int 1
  8 => int 1
  9 => int 1
  10 => int -1
  11 => int 1
  12 => int 1
  473 => int 1
  1267 => int 1
```

Line 6 should be `int 1`, as it has been executed. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is obviously that the coverage shown in output only covers the second request, as the whole PHP script is run at every request.

The easy solution consists in using two other answers : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821082/collate-several-xdebug-coverage-results-into-one-report) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167775/aggregating-code-coverage-from-several-executions-of-phpunit) to generate coverage reports using php-code-coverage https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage, and then merge all reports in an external script.

The server is now as below:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821082/collate-several-xdebug-coverage-results-into-one-report
$coverage = new PHP_CodeCoverage;
$coverage->start('Site coverage');
function shutdown() {
  global $coverage;
  $coverage->stop();
  $cov = serialize($coverage); //serialize object to disk
  file_put_contents('coverage/data.' . date('U') . '.cov', $cov);
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
$app->get('/data', function () use ($app) {
  echo "data";
});
$app->run();
```

And the merge script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167775/aggregating-code-coverage-from-several-executions-of-phpunit
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$coverage = new PHP_CodeCoverage;
$blacklist = array();
exec("find vendor -name '*'", $blacklist);
$coverage->filter()->addFilesToBlacklist($blacklist);
foreach(glob('coverage/*.cov') as $filename) {
  $cov = unserialize(file_get_contents($filename));
  $coverage->merge($cov);
}
print "\nGenerating code coverage report in HTML format ...";
$writer = new PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML(35, 70);
$writer->process($coverage, 'coverage');
print " done\n";
print "See coverage/index.html\n";
```

The merge script also puts everything in `vendor` into the blacklist.